# How do I use AJAX to print out data inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, form-submit

I have two files. One file is named index.php and another file is named process.php.

I have a form that submits to process.php in index.php:

```
<form class="form" action="process.php" method="POST" name="checkaddress" id="checkaddress">
 <table>
     <tr class="element">
          <td><label>Address</label></td>
          <td class="input"><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
     </tr>
 </table>


 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>


 </form>
 <div class="done"></div>
```

I also have a process in process.php to echo some data based off of the input. How would I be able to use AJAX to submit the form without leaving the page?

Is it something like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "process.php", 
        type: "GET",
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
        }
 });
```

What page would I put the above code on if it was right?
Also, how do I change the above code to say what the process.php outputted? For example, if I echo "Hello" on process.php, how do I make it say it in the done div?

I have seen many responses regarding AJAX, but they all rely on data that is pre-made like APIs.  I need to do a database query and fetch the data dependent on the address entered and print the data out.

Comment: $('.done').html('Hello').fadeIn('slow'); (or) $('.done').html(html).fadeIn('slow');

Comment: You would put the js snippet in index.php and use the second example in the above comment to output the response

Comment: So if my php file outputted "3rfhd" after doing a MYSQL query, ('.done').html(html).fadeIn('slow'); would show "3rfhd"?  I used it before and thought it only displays what is inside the div that was previously hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to collect the data in the form so that you can submit them to the process page, and you need to run your code when submitting the form (*and cancel the default form submission*)

```
$('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e){
    // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
    var dataToPassToAjax = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php", 
        type: "GET",
        data: dataToPassToAjax,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (resultHtml) {
            // add the returned data to the .done element
            $('.done').html( resultHtml ).fadeIn('slow');
          }
    });

  // cancel the default form submit
  return false;
});
```

---

**[update]**

If you want to modify the data before submitting them, you will have to manually create the parameters to pass to the ajax

```
$('#checkaddress').on('submit', function(e){
    // get formdata in a variable that is passed to the ajax request
    var dataToPassToAjax = {};
    var address = $('input[name="address"]', this).val();

    // alter address here
    address = 'something else';

    dataToPassToAjax.address = address;

    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php", 
        type: "GET",
        data: dataToPassToAjax,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (resultHtml ) {
            // add the returned data to the .done element
            $('.done').html(resultHtml ).fadeIn('slow');
          }
    });

  // cancel the default form submit
  return false;
});
```

Comment: OP may also want to read the [difference between return false and preventDefault()](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble understand why you put the `var data = $(this).serialize();`, can't I also do `var address= $('input[address=address]');`; why do I have to serialize it. Also, does this retrieve ALL the data from the process.php file, even echoed data?

Comment: @AnimalTesting `.serialize` will handle url encoding and will also handle multiple input elements in the form. In terms of the result from the ajax, the `html` argument you have in the `success` function will contain everything that is returned from the `process.php` page (*like doing view source on the process.php*).

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli So I would not have to set each variable manually with serialize?  If so, if the input name was "address" would the js name also be "address"?  Also what is the difference between `$('.done').html(html).` and `$('.done).replaceWith('<div class="done">'.html(html).'</div>');` or would the second code even work?

Comment: You second code would not work due to the `.` you use for concatenating strings. That is php and not javascript. `.html()` as used in my example is a jquery method that replaces the html contents of an element with whatever you pass to it (http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli But say I want to modify the input variable from the form address.  How would I do that, in other words, what variable would I use if I didn't declare one in the beginning?

Comment: @AnimalTesting not sure i follow you. The `.serialize` will create url parameters based on the `name` attribute of the form elements.

Comment: I see now, if you want to modify it then you will have to manually create the parameters you pass to the ajax call.. you are right about that.

Comment: @Gaby aka. G. Petrioli But didn't you say it will "handle multiple input elements in the form"?  What are the difference between url paramenters and variables?

Comment: @AnimalTesting added an example of manually processing the input elements. `.serialize` will create the correct *data* to pass to the ajax call for **all** elements in the form, but will do it at their current values. If you want to alter them you will have to do it one by one and then add them to an object to pass to the ajax call ..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Did you do `var data = {};` to store the data from process.php, or was it solely the purpose to store the new address variable?

Comment: @AnimalTesting, `var data = {}` was solely to store the address in it, because if you pass a javascript object to the `data` argument of the ajax it will do the url encoding on its own..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ok, thanks.  What does `data: data, ` do in ajax?

Comment: the left `data` is the name of the argument and the right `data` is the variable we created higher in the function (*the object that holds the address*). I just changed the names in the code to make it a bit more intuitive..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Oh, ok. When I try to pass some data through process.php and echo "Hello", it does not work.  Also, when I visit process.php it shows a blank page for some reason.

Comment: @AnimalTesting well, then the problem is with the process.php file.. you should post a question about it (*what you try to show and what it does show..*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I fixed the error.  In my html code I actually have two divs with class done.  Do I need to create another class to differenciate the two?  I have everything you have and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AnimalTesting if you have two elements with class `done` it will change the html in both of them, and also fade-in both.. if it is not working at all then the problem lies elsewhere.. please post a live demo..

Comment: here is a demo of the above code http://jsfiddle.net/sUm6D/ (*minor changes to make it work with jsfiddle*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thank you, I fixed by problem as one of the variables were wrong.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Is there a way where I can filter out only one variable I want in html?  For example, if resultHtml returned $don and $var, how can I only get $don?  (I would get $var later)

Comment: You will have to put them in different `div` elements with their own `id` and search in the return for them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery form plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Let me know if you want example code.